# tascam hs-p82 8 ch recorder mixer for prod recording and field recording

Tags: field-recording, portable-recorder, recorder-mixer, production-sound

I'm considering this vs the zaxcom nomad. Has anyone had experience with the Tascam?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I'd choose Nomad if I were you. pros of the Nomad are the number of inputs, very low power consumption, and it's a very bag friendly recorder (if that's important for you). Have only dr-680 experience (a good one nonetheless) but this is a different price bracket. You should compare Tascam with both SD 788T and Nomad, and choose the one that suits your needs better.

Comment: Thanks @Bartoz Idzi, Im confused now, the Tascam has 8 inputs where the Nomad at the same price point starts with only 6. I do plan on comparing them when I can find someone that has them or can rent them nearby. Neither are for rent in my area yet. The Nomad also only records up to 48kHz to my knowledge and I require recordings at high samplerates in addition to on set dialogue we will use it for SFX. Am I mistaken with any of this information? 

Cheers!

Comment: here is the manual: http://www.zaxcom.com/manuals/Zaxcom%20Nomad%20User%20Manual%20-%20January%202012%20Revision.pdf
The Nomad is pretty new. Though Zaxcom seems to be a company with good reputation. I don't know anybody that would choose Tascam over SD stuff tho. Could be just the ticket for you! I'd test drive the unit - i think it's possible to arrange that with a dealer?

Comment: @ Matt  Nomad does do 96k recording but its a bit buggy right now.  There is a metric ton of information on the nomad at the jwsound.net forums